# Active ADFS authentication, token is always invalid

Tags: javascript, claims-based-auth, adfs

I am attempting JS-based ADFS authentication to consume SharePoint resources.

I am using active authentication (browserless) to get a SAML token from the ADFS server. A portion of the XML I get back from the SOAP call is

```
            <trust:RequestedSecurityToken>
                <Assertion ID="_d448ea5a-c8b0-4906-b84d-5b3ce09cd172" IssueInstant="2016-03-14T19:48:25.639Z" Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
                    <Issuer>http://sts.***.com/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
                    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        <ds:SignedInfo>
                            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                            <ds:Reference URI="#_d448ea5a-c8b0-4906-b84d-5b3ce09cd172">
                                <ds:Transforms>
                                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                                </ds:Transforms>
                                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                <ds:DigestValue>97v...</ds:DigestValue>
                            </ds:Reference>
                        </ds:SignedInfo>
                        <ds:SignatureValue>tXt/Wc...</ds:SignatureValue>
                        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                            <ds:X509Data>
                                <ds:X509Certificate>MII...</ds:X509Certificate>
                            </ds:X509Data>
                        </KeyInfo>
                    </ds:Signature>
                    <Subject>
                        <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                            <SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2016-03-14T19:53:25.639Z"/>
                        </SubjectConfirmation>
                    </Subject>
                    <Conditions NotBefore="2016-03-14T19:48:25.639Z" NotOnOrAfter="2016-03-14T20:48:25.639Z">
                        <AudienceRestriction>
                            <Audience>https://apps.***./trust</Audience>
                        </AudienceRestriction>
                    </Conditions>
                    <AttributeStatement>
                        <Attribute Name="* UPN">
                            <AttributeValue>***</AttributeValue>
                        </Attribute>
                    </AttributeStatement>
                    <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2016-03-14T19:48:25.560Z">
                        <AuthnContext>
                            <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</AuthnContextClassRef>
                        </AuthnContext>
                    </AuthnStatement>
                </Assertion>
            </trust:RequestedSecurityToken>
```

I then craft an HTTP GET against the SharePoint server  with the following headers:

```
Accept: aplication/json;odata=verbose
Content-type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Authorization: Bearer tXt/Wc...
```

The response is an HTTP 401 Unauthorized with the body of:

```
{"error_description":"Unsupported security token."}
```

My immediate suspicion is that either I've done something wrong but haven't noticed it, or that there is some issue with the STS server passing the token to the SharePoint server. Can anyone shed some light on either process or configuration issues that might cause this?